# What does the notation $P_{ij} ([i, j],[i, j])$ mean for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking at my notes from class. We are given a matrix $A$, and in connection to Givens rotations, I see the notation $P_{ij} ([i, j],[i, j]) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c & s\\
-s & c
\end{bmatrix}
$

So I assume it means "the $2 \times 2$ matrix with entry $1, 1$ being entry $a_{ii}$ of $A$, entry $1, 2$ being entry $a_{ij}$ of $A$, etc."

Is this what the notation really means?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what's the dimension of matrix A?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio It's not specified, but I assume it's allowed to be a rectangular matrix with more rows than columns.